# Как разграничить логирование по уровням и выходным приемникам?

Tags: golang

Я использую logrus для логирования в Golang. Логи идут в два приемника: stdout и файл. Для объединения используется стандартный мультирайтер. Но хотелось бы разделить логи не только по приемникам, но и по уровням. Чтобы в stdout шли логи уровня INFO, а вот в файл писались только ошибки. Существует ли такая возможность разграничения в logrus или каком-то ином логгере?

```
logWriter, err := os.OpenFile(
    logFile,
    os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY,
    0644,
)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("[LOGFILE] %s", err.Error())
} else {
    log.Infof("[LOGFILE]:%s\n", logFile)
}

mw = io.MultiWriter(
    ansicolor.NewAnsiColorWriter(os.Stdout),
    logWriter,
)
log.SetOutput(mw)
```

Answer (score 0):

На уровне `Writer` эту задачу решить нельзя, т.к. информация об уровне, на котором было залогировано сообщение, уже потеряна. Решить эту задачу в рамках `logrus` можно используя `Hooks`.

Сам `logger` пишет в `os.Stdout`, но в `logger` добавляется `hook` на нужные уровни, который пишет в файл:

```
import "github.com/sirupsen/logrus/hooks/writer"

...

log.Hooks.Add(&writer.Hook{
    Writer: logWriter,
    LogLevels: []logrus.Level{logrus.Error},
})
```

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Сделал примерно так как и написали.

Answer (score 0):

По совету Pavel Borzenkov решил свой вопрос так:

```
import (
log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
"github.com/sirupsen/logrus/hooks/writer"
)    
...
    //----------------------------
    // конфигурация логгера
    log.SetFormatter(&log.TextFormatter{
        ForceColors:     true,
        FullTimestamp:   true,
        TimestampFormat: "01/02 15:04:05",
    })
    log.SetOutput(ansicolor.NewAnsiColorWriter(os.Stdout))
    log.SetLevel(log.Level(*logLevel))  //log.DebugLevel



    log.AddHook (&writer.Hook{
        Writer: logWriter,
        LogLevels: []log.Level{
            log.PanicLevel,
            log.FatalLevel, 
            log.ErrorLevel, 
            log.WarnLevel,
            log.InfoLevel,
        },
})


А те сообщения, которые я не хотел видеть в файловом логе (они выводились в цикле) сделал дебаговыми.
```